# Asp.Net: Is a GridView really able to handle for all browsers or only a pain?

Tags: asp.net, css, gridview, cross-browser

I am Asp.Net Developer since 3 years now.
I had different projects in which we used the ASP.Net-GridView-Control.

The problem ist, we had really really a pain by designing the GridView. We need around 2-10 hours per GridView only for a simple design. It was such a pain, you didn't believe. (and Yes, we really used CSS and so on!). Even after very much work on the GridViews it doesn't look the same in every browser. In IE7/8 it looks still different as in FF 3/4 or IE9.

My newest project need to 100% a same looking user interface in every browser and need 100% well design and style. So there is no space for CSS&GridView-Bugs (I can list you over 20 of these!) or hours after hours for a simple GridView to design.

So my question is:

- Is it able to handle the different lookings in browsers for the GridView?
- Did I miss anything in styling a gridView, which can cause my unlimited pain with GridViews?
- Is there another easy and good control, which I can bind on an ObjectDataSource and work with, which has nearly the same functions as a GridView? (Example: bind ImageButtons on a coloum)

Comment: I am not a CSS guru so I won't even attempt to answer this question.  However my first reaction to reading this is that you must be crazy to think you can EASILY get ANYTHING to display 100% the same in every version of every browser.

Comment: @pseudocoder, good point and I would add that we should never even try to get something the same in every browser :)

Comment: I don't agree. When I write my code by miself (e.g: a Div-Contaier or a Table) I didn't need any time addition to make my design looking the same in all browsers because after nearly 4 years of experience of cross-browser programming I know nearly every single CSS-Style / Design-Bug and SCC-Style / Design-Difference of common browsers like IE 7/8/9, FF3/4, Opera9/10/11 and Safari.

Comment: @Kovu, here's an opinion from one of the most gifted professionals in this field http://24ways.org/2009/ignorance-is-bliss

Comment: Very nice article :) Get a +1 for that :) But really, when a customer has on one of his highest prioritise-list the point "all browser have to look the same", you can't say no, because it's the customer, right? :)

Comment: @Kovu, my answer to him would be to show him the stats because at the end of the day they never argue about ROI ;-)

Comment: @Kovu, Tell the client it will take $x to get it done the "easy" way, letting the browsers have differences, but keeping things simple, more future-proof, etc.  It will take 3 * $x to get it almost pixel perfect in all the current browsers, with no guarantee it will be the same in future browsers.

Comment: Have you tried Theming and Skining? You could spend some time making one GridView skin near perfect and then reusing that skin all across the website...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a ListView. It makes no difference if you use CSS with the GridView because the GridView will still create a table-based layout. By using the ItemTemplates with the ListView , you can have total control over the markup generated with CSS. Of course, tabular data still warrants the use of tables...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337898.aspx

Once you have your CSS-based layout being generated, you can use the HTML5Boilerplate project to gain cross-browser compatibility in a 'graceful degradation' manner:

http://html5boilerplate.com/

Answer (score 1):

> We need around 2-10 hours per GridView
>   only for a simple design.

and

> need to 100% a same looking user
>   interface in every browser and need
>   100% well design and style.

By the sound of it, you *need* to buy a third party toolset like DevExpress, Infragistics,  Telerek, or etc. instead.  These companies have already figured out how to solve these needs.  The cost can be easily justified based on the first need alone.

So the answer is: buy a third-party toolkit.

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look into this, maybe you are right :)